# Expand Bottom Sheet without a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gesture, bottom-sheet

I've created a bottom sheet that swipes up when a button on the screen is clicked. The main activity is a map - with a button that expands the bottom sheet. I'm using the Material Bottom sheet library.

Main Screen:
[Hidden Bottom Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ6Xi.png)

Expanded Bottom Sheet on click:
[Expanded Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrfWv.jpg)

```
       mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);

            }
        });
```

**Here's want I want to implement:**

Instead of having to press a button to expand the sheet, I want the user to be able to swipe up and open the bottom sheet.

[This is what I want the bottom sheet to look like hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co8Ag.png)

I've tried using Gesture Listener but that doesn't seem to work - since the main screen has a map. It only moves the map around and swipe isn't recognized.

I'm fairly new to android so I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bottom sheet layout xml, add this code

```
app:behavior_peekHeight="20dp" // change the dp as your need
```